# Magento Incorrect Collection count with filters

Tags: php, magento

The below code I am trying to create a product collection and filter it, however, it is not giving me an accurate product count and I'm not sure why.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addFieldToFilter(array(
                array('attribute'=>'distributor','in'=>array(intval($distributor))),

        ))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                array('finset' => strval($cat->getId())),
        ));
$count = $collection->getSize();
```

For example, I have a category with that distributor filter that has around 30 products but the count from the above code shows 20.  Same for another one that has 3 products but that count brings back 2.

UPDATE : Fixed the issue myself using finset instead.  See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question.  Used finset for distributor because it is a multselect.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

                    $dists = array(
                      array(
                        "finset" => array(intval($distributor))
                      ),
                    );

                    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left outer')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter("distributor", $dists)
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
                         array('finset' => $cat->getId()),
                    ));
                    $collection->load();
                    $count = $collection->getSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try get your query code from this collection and run it direct on your database. And you can check if the query is correct.

try this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: The count that is displayed is accurate to the count I am getting, yes.  What I am trying to do is mimic the results that advanced search would bring back.  for example /advanced/result/?distributor%5B%5D=13&category=19   That particular restult brings back over 100 results yet the filter code above only shows a count of 90.

Comment: When i get under value then i expect i look for the query and test if it right. Someday my product grid dont bring all products and i found one wrong join. I dont know the aswer of your question but i think it is the right way.